# UIBezierPath Rounded corners

Tags: swift, swift3, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I am trying to make this image appear with some rounded corners, dictated in code below[image: This shape with rounded edges]

My code for this is as follows. I want path[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9Qax.png),path[4], path[5] rounded. I am open to a different approach. Please dont recommend UIBezierPath(roundedRect:..) as I dont need corenrs 0,2 rounded. This is tricky!

```
        let width = self.view.frame.size.width
        let trianglePath = UIBezierPath()
        var pts = [CGPoint(x:  2 * width / 16, y: width / 16),
               CGPoint(x: width / 32, y: width / 16 + width / 16),
               CGPoint(x: 2 * width / 16 , y: width / 16 + width / 8),
               CGPoint(x: width / 5  + 2 * width / 16, y: width / 8 + width / 16),
               CGPoint(x: width / 5  + 2 * width / 16, y: width / 16 ),
               CGPoint(x: 2 * width / 16, y:  width / 16 )
        ]

      // this path replaces this, because i cannot easily add rectangle
        //var path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: width / 37.5).cgPath

        trianglePath.move(to: pts[0])
        trianglePath.addLine(to: pts[1]) // needs to be rounded
        trianglePath.addLine(to: pts[2])
        trianglePath.addLine(to: pts[3])
        trianglePath.addLine(to: pts[4]) // needs to be rounded
        trianglePath.addLine(to: pts[5]) // needs to be rounded
        trianglePath.close()

        let layer = CAShapeLayer()

        layer.path = trianglePath.cgPath
        layer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        layer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
        layer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
        layer.zPosition = 4
        layer.isHidden = false
        view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
```

Comment: "Please dont recommend UIBezierPath" Please don't tell people what to recommend. You worry about asking the _question_ clearly (which you are not doing so far) and let people who know more than you worry about what the answer might be. Try showing a drawing of the shape you _want_ - so far, it is utterly unclear what you'd like to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a clipping path as explained here: https://www.raywenderlich.com/162313/core-graphics-tutorial-part-2-gradients-contexts

Specifically this bit:

```
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect,
              byRoundingCorners: .allCorners,
                    cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 8.0, height: 8.0))
path.addClip()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make rounded shapes you must use

```
trianglePath.AddArcToPoint(...);
```

See documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH11-SW5

To be extra helpful, here is an entire subclass which you can use to learn how to draw custom views. Hope this helps.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

final class BorderedView:UIView
{
    var drawTopBorder = false
    var drawBottomBorder = false
    var drawLeftBorder = false
    var drawRightBorder = false

    var topBorderColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.4)
    var leftBorderColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.4)
    var rightBorderColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.6)
    var bottomBorderColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.6)

    var upperLeftCornerRadius:CGFloat = 0
    var upperRightCornerRadius:CGFloat = 0
    var lowerLeftCornerRadius:CGFloat = 0
    var lowerRightCornerRadius:CGFloat = 0

    var subview:UIView?
    fileprivate var visibleView:UIView!
    fileprivate var _backgroundColor:UIColor!

    override init(frame: CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        super.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        super.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    func setVisibleBackgroundColor(_ color:UIColor)
    {
        _backgroundColor = color
    }

    func setBackgroundGradient(_ gradient:CAGradientLayer)
    {
        gradient.frame = visibleView.bounds
        gradient.masksToBounds = true
        visibleView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    }

    func drawView()
    {
        visibleView = UIView(frame: self.frame)
        visibleView.backgroundColor = _backgroundColor
        visibleView.clipsToBounds = true
        if let v = subview
        {
            visibleView.addSubview(v)
        }
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
    {
        // Drawing code
        let width = rect.size.width - 0.5;
        let height = rect.size.height - 0.5;

        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        let w = self.frame.size.width;
        let h = self.frame.size.height;

        // Create clipping area as path.
        let path = CGMutablePath();
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: upperLeftCornerRadius))
        path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), tangent2End: CGPoint(x: upperLeftCornerRadius, y: 0), radius: upperLeftCornerRadius)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: w - upperRightCornerRadius, y: 0))
        path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: w, y: 0), tangent2End: CGPoint(x: w, y: upperRightCornerRadius), radius: upperRightCornerRadius)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: w, y: h - lowerRightCornerRadius))
        path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: w, y: h), tangent2End: CGPoint(x: w - lowerRightCornerRadius, y: h), radius: lowerRightCornerRadius)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: lowerLeftCornerRadius, y: h))
        path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: 0, y: h), tangent2End: CGPoint(x: 0, y: h - lowerLeftCornerRadius), radius: lowerLeftCornerRadius)
        path.closeSubpath();
        // Add clipping area to path
        context.addPath(path);
        // Clip to the path and draw the image
        context.clip ();

        self.drawView()
        visibleView.layer.render(in: context)

        // ********** Your drawing code here **********
        context.setLineWidth(0.5);
        var stroke = false

        if (drawTopBorder)
        {
            context.setStrokeColor(topBorderColor.cgColor);
            context.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)); //start at this point
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: 0.5)); //draw to this point
            stroke = true
        }

        if (drawLeftBorder)
        {
            context.setStrokeColor(leftBorderColor.cgColor);
            context.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)); //start at this point
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: height)); //draw to this point
            stroke = true
        }

        if (drawBottomBorder)
        {
            context.setStrokeColor(bottomBorderColor.cgColor);
            context.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: height)); //start at this point
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: height)); //draw to this point
            stroke = true
        }

        if (drawRightBorder)
        {
            context.setStrokeColor(rightBorderColor.cgColor);
            context.move(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: 0.5)); //start at this point
            context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: height)); //draw to this point
            stroke = true
        }

        // and now draw the Path!
        if stroke
        {
            context.strokePath();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bjorn, my question is why does layer.linecap and layer.linejoin not make the connections round, as per apple docs? @bjørn-ruthberg

Comment: They do, but this is very small details. You would want something like 3 to 5 points to see a nice rounded border. Then you need to use the addarctopoint method. it takes some effort to get your head around, but once you get it, it'll be your go-to solution :)

Comment: I updated my answer to include an example class. You can mess around with that until you get the shape you want. If you need any explanations, just ask.